# How to make Macro?

Tags: ios, macros

I want to add this line to Constants.h and I want to call it anywhere in my app.

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0
```

I have done following and using, but exactly I have no idea how to make it?

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Apple suggest that you use the the following to detect the system version: `if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {` will return true on devices running iOS 7. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1

Comment: Why do you need to check the OS version so much in your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eloborate macro in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475183/eloborate-macro-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define IS_IOS_7 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
```

Comment: We say thanks here by accepting the answer :) See edit though. It's OS version, not hardware's that we're checking.

Comment: I know, but stack overflow doesn't allow acceptance until a particular time. I will accept as the time will be over and I will be able to accept it. Thanks again...