# Eloborate macro in iOS?

Tags: ios, macros

Can anyone guide me how the following Macro is exactly working?

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Comment: Now that you understand what the macro does you might want to know that the funny epsilon/fabs comparison together with the double cast is utter nonsense. Both floats and doubles can represent 568.0 exactly and are guaranteed to do so without loss of precision or unexpected equality test results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros all work the same way: the compiler simply replaces the macro name with the definition, so if you have:

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {...}
```

it's the same thing as:

```
if (( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON ))
```

Now, if you're not sure what that code does, break it down:

```
( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568
```

This part gets the height of the main screen and subtracts 568. Stepping out, we have:

```
( fabs( ... < DBL_EPSILON ))
```

This compares the result just computed to DBL_EPSILON to see whether the result is within the limits of a rounding error. I'm not sure why it's necessary to take the absolute value of the result, but that's what it does.

In a nutshell, the macro doesn't really check that you're running on an iPhone 5. Instead, it tells you whether you're running on a device that has a screen that's 568 pixels in height.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is just checking if your screen's height is 568 pixels. DBL_EPSILON is used to compare two floats, it's safer to use a quantised float increment when comparing floats because otherwise you can get wrong comparison results.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain it:

If  the absolute value of `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` (the height of the screen) - `568` is less than `DBL_EPSILON`, it means that the screen is iPhone5 screen.

Is the same as doing

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - 568 == 0
```

But doing it in that way in order to protect against float error comparison results.